# join CassandraTableScanRDD[CassandraRow] with RDD[String]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I am writing a program where I have a RDD[String] and a CassandraTableScanRDD and i want to do a left join between them.

Is this possible? From what I saw online that joins were only happing between CassandraTableScanRDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join` functions are available for `PairRDD` objects (see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.html)).

A `PairRDD` object is an RDD of key-value pairs, for example: `RDD[(Int, String)]`

Typically you create a `PairRDD` object from a regular `RDD` using the `keyBy` function, which allows you to specify which key to use. Then when you run `join`, it joins elements whose keys are equal.